# Identifying inspiration among Black Mirror episode and Sword Art Online

Tags: reference, trope, black-mirror, anime

I just watched 'Black Mirror' episode 4 of season 3 (11 episode of whole) titled 'San Junipero'

Lots of concepts were similar to the last quarter of 'Sword Art Online' anime 'Mother Rosario'

- Using virtual reality for therapy or rehabilitation purposes.
- Spending huge part of one's own life in VR due to health issues.
- Homosexual relationship among protagonists in Black Mirror which resulted in marriage compared to a joke said by Yuuki to Asuna about inability to get married with her because she would change her name into Yuuki Yuuki (Asuna's surname)

My question is: **Is it possible that these productions were somehow influenced by one another?** Or is it common trope in SciFi or simple coincidence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the origin of the 'meme' is Neal Stephenson's [Snow Crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_Crash) (1992) though you could make strong representations for the online world [Second Life](https://secondlife.com) (2004) to be a more contemporary origin - in as much as it 'exists', unlike the world of Snow Crash [the Metaverse] which was only ever on paper.

Comment: As I understand, I gained downvotes because my question can cause subjective, opinion based answers. But this is answer I was looking for. Thank you!